# symfony many to many in embedded form

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, many-to-many, relation

I have a problem with embbed form from Model which has many to many relation. The embedded form will save the model correctly but will not save many to many relations.

Example:

Schema.yml:

```
Mother:
  columns:
    name:
      type: string(80)

Color:
  columns:
    name:
      type: string(80)

Child:
  columns:
    mother_id:
      type: integer
    name:
      type: string(80)
  relations:
    Mother:
      class: Mother
      local: mother_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
      onDelete: cascade
      foreignType: one
      foreignAlias: Children
    FavoriteColors:
      class: Color
      refClass: ChildColor
      local: child_id
      foreign: color_id
      onDelete: cascade
      foreignAlias: Children

ChildColor:
  columns:
    child_id:
      type: integer
    color_id:
      type: integer
```

Then I just modify MotherForm.class.php:

```
class MotherForm extends BaseMotherForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->embedForm('child', new ChildForm($this->getObject()->getChildren()));
  }
}
```

and ChildForm.class.php:

```
class ChildForm extends BaseChildForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    unset($this['mother_id']);
  }
}
```

I generate the module with doctrine:

```
php symfony doctrine:generate-module frontend mother Mother
```

Put some color data:

```
Color:
  Color_1:
    name: blue
  Color_2:
    name: red
  Color_3:
    name: green
  Color_4:
    name: purple
```

When I call /frontend_dev.php/mother/new I can add a new one, name of Mother and Child are updated but favorite color are never saved...

If I add a relation between a color and a child with phpmyadmin and then /edit call. Then the right color is in the multiple select selected, but I can't edit it.

Is it a bug from Symfony or should I do something else ?

UPDATE:
If I generate the module for the model Child. I can edit favorite colors but the form is not embedded anymore...

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue than you. [Ticket #5867 in symfony](http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/5867) is all about this issue, and a lot of people have lost a lot of time with it.

In the ticket, some people give solutions. You can try them, but I don't know why they didn't work in my case.

I have suceed with a [solution found in this post](http://symfonyguide.wordpress.com/2009/09/28/symfony-forms-saving-process/). It's a very useful post, which explains the reason of this bug and a workaround.

Basically, the bug is due to the fact that when saving embedded forms, symfony calls `save()` in the embedded object, but not in the embedded form, and `save()` in an object doesn't update related tables.

To solve it you must overwrite `//lib/form/doctrine/BaseFormDoctrine.class.php` (or the Propel equivalent, but then substitue Doctrine for Propel in following code):

Create the function `bindEmbeddedForms()` this way:

```
public function bindEmbeddedForms($embedded_forms, $values)
{
  if($this->isValid())
  {
    foreach ($embedded_forms as $name => $form)
    {
      $form->isBound = true;
      $form->values = $values[$name];

      if ($form->embeddedForms)
      {
        $this->bindEmbeddedForms($form->embeddedForms, $values[$name]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Declare `bind()` function calling its parent one this way:

```
public function bind(array $taintedValues = null, array $taintedFiles = null)
{
   parent::bind($taintedValues, $taintedFiles);
   $this->bindEmbeddedForms($this->embeddedForms, $this->getValues());
}
```

And overwrite `saveEmbeddedForms()`this way:

```
public function saveEmbeddedForms($con = null, $forms = null)
{
  if (is_null($con))
  {
    $con = $this->getConnection();
  }

  if (is_null($forms))
  {
    $forms = $this->embeddedForms;
  }

  foreach ($forms as $key => $form)
  {
    if ($form instanceof sfFormDoctrine)
    {
      if(method_exists(new $form(), 'doSaveManyToMany'))
      {
        $form->doSaveManyToMany($con);
      }
      else
      {
        $form->getObject()->save($con);
      }
      $form->saveEmbeddedForms($con);
    }
    else
    {
      $this->saveEmbeddedForms($con, $form->getEmbeddedForms());
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in your embedded form class (in the post it do this as well in `BaseFormDoctrine` class, but I think it's cleaner my way), create the method `doSaveManyToMany` which save your relations:

```
public function doSaveManyToMany($con = null)
{
  if (is_null($con))
  {
    $con = $this->getConnection();
  }

  $this->object->save($con);
  /*
  * Save the many-2-many relationship
  */
  $this->save***List($con); //Ex: $this->saveAhasBList($con)
}
```

Some people say to have some problem in the post comments and say a solution, but it wasn't my case.

Hope it helps somebody, even if my answer is for a quite old opened question.

Comment: Thanks, very useful your comment. I'm not a fan of update symfony core, I hope that a fix is coming ... I can't find it anymore, but I think that I solved this problem by saving it by my self in the parent form (the MotherForm in my example).